# Android Alarm start on boot

Tags: android, notifications, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, bootcompleted

I would like to send a notification on specific day of the week, my code works on the day but every times I turn on my smartphone/emulator I get the notification. How can i fix this problem?

My Manifest

```
 <receiver android:name=".AutoStart">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name=".Alarm"></receiver>
        <receiver android:name=".NotificationActivity"></receiver>
```

AutoStart.java

```
    public class AutoStart extends BroadcastReceiver
{   
    Alarm alarm = new Alarm();
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {   
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"))
        {
            alarm.SetAlarm(context);
        }
    }
}
```

And my Alarm.java

```
    @SuppressLint("Wakelock")
    public class Alarm extends BroadcastReceiver 
    {    
        static RSSFeed myRssFeed = null;
         @Override
         public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
         {   

             PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
             PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "");
             wl.acquire();

             SetAlarm(context);

             wl.release();
         }

    public void SetAlarm(Context context)
     {
         AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
         Intent i = new Intent(context, NotificationActivity.class);
         PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
         Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
         calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 2);
         calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9);
         calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
         calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
         am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi); 
     }

     public void CancelAlarm(Context context)
     {
         Intent intent = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
         PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
         AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
         alarmManager.cancel(sender);
     }
 }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Because you have declared android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED permission in your manifest.It means whenever Your device or phone restarts it will call the BroadcastReceiver.

Try the following.
This is working code. It wakes CPU every 10 minutes until the phone turns off.

Add to Manifest.xml:

...

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"></uses-permission>
```

...

```
<receiver  android:process=":remote" android:name="Alarm"></receiver>
```

...
Code:

```
package YourPackage;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Alarm extends BroadcastReceiver 
{    
     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
     {   
         PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
         PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "");
         wl.acquire();

         // Put here YOUR code.
         Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm !!!!!!!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // For example

         wl.release();
     }

 public void SetAlarm(Context context)
 {
     AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
     Intent i = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
     PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
     am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 10, pi); // Millisec * Second * Minute
 }

 public void CancelAlarm(Context context)
 {
     Intent intent = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
     PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
     AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
     alarmManager.cancel(sender);
 }
 }
```

Set Alarm from Service:

```
 package YourPackage;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;

public class YourService extends Service
{
Alarm alarm = new Alarm();
public void onCreate()
{
    super.onCreate();       
}

public void onStart(Context context,Intent intent, int startId)
{
    alarm.SetAlarm(context);
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) 
{
    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I had <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/> and in the receiver I can't change <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>